# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS while Applying filter to CIImage [Core Image]

Tags: ios, objective-c, filter, uicollectionview, core-image

I am Working on Imagebase Application. I want to Apply some filter on Images. For that I have used [Core Image].

I have stored some FilterName in array and to show filter effect as preview I am using UICollection view. When user tap on Preview image then Filter will be apply on Main Imageview. But when I tap on preview cell , then filter applied successfully on Main Imageview. but after that when I am dragging collection view cell to apply next preview I am getting BAD_ACCESS Error on Filter Method.

`-(UIImage *) applyFilter: (UIImage*) picture withFilterName:(NSString*)Filtername`

Here is my Code to apply Filter :-

---

Initial setup with Filter array and RegisterCollectionview cell:-

```
-(void)setUpDefaultUI{
    [self HideControlsAndSetupUI];

    arrFilter = @[ @"Original",
                   @"CILinearToSRGBToneCurve",
                   @"CIPhotoEffectChrome",
                   @"CIPhotoEffectFade",
                   @"CIPhotoEffectInstant",
                   @"CIPhotoEffectMono",
                   @"CIPhotoEffectNoir",
                   @"CIPhotoEffectProcess",
                   @"CIPhotoEffectTonal",
                   @"CIPhotoEffectTransfer",
                   @"CISRGBToneCurveToLinear",
                   @"CIVignette",
                   // @"CIVignetteEffect",
                   @"CISepiaTone",
                   ];

    [self.vwCollection registerClass:[ActivityCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ActivityCollectionViewCell"];
    [self.vwCollection registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ActivityCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ActivityCollectionViewCell"];
    _imgEdit.image=_stillImage; // To apply filter on this Image 
    _OriginalImage=_stillImage; // Original image if user declined to use filter
```

}

---

CollectionView Datasource:-

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    NSLog(@"filterAvailable");

    ActivityCollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ActivityCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *xib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ActivityCollectionViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [xib objectAtIndex:0];
        [cell.imgVw setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    }
      if (indexPath.item==0) {
        cell.imgVw.image = _OriginalImage; //Original Image on 0 index
    }else{
         UIImage *img=[self applyFilter:_stillImage withFilterName:[arrFilter objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; // Apply filter on this method
        cell.imgVw.image=img;
}
    return cell;
}
```

---

Collectionview Delegate :-

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ActivityCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ActivityCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *xib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ActivityCollectionViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [xib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
 if (indexPath.item==0) {
        _imgEdit.image=_OriginalImage; // Set original image in main Imageview
    }else{
        UIImage *img=[self applyFilter:_stillImage withFilterName:[arrFilter objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        _imgEdit.image = img;  // Apply filter on Main Imageview 
    }
    }
```

---

Filter Apply from This Method :-

```
-(UIImage *) applyFilter: (UIImage*) picture withFilterName:(NSString*)Filtername
{
    UIImageOrientation originalOrientation = picture.imageOrientation;
    CGFloat originalScale = picture.scale;
    CIImage *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:picture.CGImage];
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
     CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:Filtername keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, nil, [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.7], nil];
    CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
    CGImageRef cgimg =
    [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
    UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg scale:originalScale orientation:originalOrientation];

    //CGImageRelease(CGImageRef) method.
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
    return newImg;

}
```

---

Image of Error:-
 - BAD_ACCESS
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally , I got the problem. Actually the problem is , I am applying filter on Still image in Both the method.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

and

```
 - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
```

So, Final solution is use different image in Both the methods .

Here is the code :-
//Initial Setup
    -(void)setUpDefaultUI{
        [self HideControlsAndSetupUI];

```
    arrFilter = @[ @"Original",
                   @"CILinearToSRGBToneCurve",
                   @"CIPhotoEffectChrome",
                   @"CIPhotoEffectFade",
                   @"CIPhotoEffectInstant",
                   @"CIPhotoEffectMono",
                   @"CIPhotoEffectNoir",
                   @"CIPhotoEffectProcess",
                   @"CIPhotoEffectTonal",
                   @"CIPhotoEffectTransfer",
                   @"CISRGBToneCurveToLinear",
                   @"CIVignette",
                   // @"CIVignetteEffect",
                   @"CISepiaTone",
                   ];

    [self.vwCollection registerClass:[ActivityCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ActivityCollectionViewCell"];
    [self.vwCollection registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ActivityCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ActivityCollectionViewCell"];
    _imgEdit.image=_stillImage;
    _OriginalImage=_stillImage;
    temp=_OriginalImage;
}
```

//Datasource method To display image in collection view with filter

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    NSLog(@"filterAvailable");

    ActivityCollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ActivityCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];



    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *xib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ActivityCollectionViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [xib objectAtIndex:0];
        //[cell.imgVw setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
        cell.imgVw.clipsToBounds = YES;

        cell.imgVw.layer.cornerRadius = 5;

    }
  if (indexPath.item==0) {
        cell.imgVw.image = _OriginalImage; //Set original image of 1st index

    }else{
        UIImage *img=[self applyFilter:temp withFilterName:[arrFilter objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];    // Set temp image in place of stilimage
        cell.imgVw.image=img;

        }
 return cell;
}
```

//Apply filter on Main Imageview .

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (_EnumPhotos==defaultPhotos) {

    if (indexPath.item==0) {
        _imgEdit.image=_OriginalImage; //If user click on 1st index then original filter applied on main image
    }else{

         UIImage *img=[self applyFilter:_stillImage withFilterName:[arrFilter objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; // Use still image here .
        _imgEdit.image = img; // Apply image on main image view
    }
    }
}
```

//Apply filter Method

```
-(UIImage *) applyFilter: (UIImage*) picture withFilterName:(NSString*)Filtername
{
    UIImageOrientation originalOrientation = picture.imageOrientation;
    CGFloat originalScale = picture.scale;
    CIImage *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:picture.CGImage];
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
     CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:Filtername keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, nil, [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.7], nil];
    CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
    CGImageRef cgimg =
    [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
    UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg scale:originalScale orientation:originalOrientation];

    //CGImageRelease(CGImageRef) method.
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
    return newImg;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you certain `picture` is a valid `UIImage` object? Put a breakpoint at the start of `applyFilter:withFilterName:`, and use Xcode's quick-look to confirm it is what you think it is.
2. Also check `Filtername` is a valid string.

If those are both correct, this looks suspicious:

`CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:Filtername keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, nil, [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.7], nil];`

The keys & values here are a nil-terminated list. Try removing everything after the first `nil`:

`CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:Filtername keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, nil];`

Also note that both `CIVignette` & `CISepiaTone` have additional input parameters (see Apple's [Core Image Filter Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIVignette))